# Prove that if $X_n \to X$ in probability and $X_n \to Y$ in probability then $X = Y$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I want to prove that if $X_n \to X$ in probability and $X_n \to Y$  in probability then $X = Y$ almost surely.

By definition, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_n - X| \geq \epsilon) = 0$$
$$\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_n - Y| \geq \epsilon) = 0$$

I should now prove that $$\mathbb{P}(X \neq Y) = 0$$

Maybe I should show that for any $\epsilon > 0$

$$\mathbb{P}(|X - Y| > \epsilon) = 0$$

which is equivalent to what I want to prove, but isn't helpful, because $|X - Y|$ is not greater $|X_n - X| + |X_n - Y|$ anyway (not vise-versa).

Any ideas, how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $\epsilon>0$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(|X - Y| > \epsilon) &=\mathsf{P}(|X -X_n+X_n- Y| > \epsilon) \\
&\le \mathsf{P}(|X_n-X|+|X_n- Y| > \epsilon) \\
&\le \mathsf{P}(|X_n-X| > \epsilon/2)+\mathsf{P}(|X_n- Y| > \epsilon/2)\to 0
\end{align}
as $n\to\infty$, which implies that $\mathsf{P}(|X - Y| > \epsilon)=0$. Thus,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X\ne Y)=\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{k\ge 1}|X-Y|>k^{-1}\right)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathsf{P}(|X-Y|>k^{-1})=0.
$$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't quite understand though, why $\mathsf{P}(|X -X_n+X_n- Y| > \epsilon) \le \mathsf{P}(|X_n-X| > \epsilon/2)+\mathsf{P}(|X_n- Y| > \epsilon/2)$? Maybe it follows from $\mathsf{P}(|X -X_n+X_n- Y| > \epsilon) < \mathsf{P}(\{|X -X_n| > \epsilon/2\} \cup \{|Y -X_n| > \epsilon/2\})$, but I don't quite get why the latter inequality should be true, either.

Comment: For nonnegative r.v.s $Z$ and $W$, $\{Z+W>\epsilon\}\subset\{Z>\epsilon/2\}\cup\{W>\epsilon/2\}$.

Comment: thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry, I think I found a flaw in your reasoning. In the first step, you seem to be considering the limit of $\mathsf{P}(|X_n-X| > \epsilon/2)+\mathsf{P}(|X_n- Y| > \epsilon/2)$ for $n \to +\infty$, not $\epsilon \to 0$. But in the second step, you use the result from the first step as if we proved that $\mathsf{P}(|X - Y| > \epsilon) \to 0$ when $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: So what? The first step shows that $\mathsf{P}(|X-Y|>\epsilon)=0$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: You're right, sorry!