# Convergence in probability as well as almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $(X_n)_n$ converges to T in probability and also $(X_n)_n$ converges almost surely to Y can we say that $$P(T=Y)=1$$?

Comment: yes, note that convergence in probability imply that there is a subsequence of $(X_n)$ that converges pointwise a.s. to $T$, so...

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3994077/prove-that-if-x-n-to-x-in-probability-and-x-n-to-y-in-probability-then-x/3994195#3994195

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_n$ converges to $Y$ almost surely implies that $X_n$ converges to $Y$ in probability. You already know that $X_n$ converges to $T$ in probability. Therefore $Y=T$ almost surely.
Note that
$$
|Y-T|\leq |Y-X_n|+|T-X_n.|
$$
Therefore $|Y-T|>\varepsilon$ implies $|Y-X_n|>\varepsilon/2$ or $|T-X_n|>\varepsilon/2$. Thus, for any fixed $\varepsilon>0$
$$
\mathbb{P}(|Y-T|>\varepsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}(|X_n-T|>\varepsilon/2) + \mathbb{P}(|X_n-Y|>\varepsilon/2) 
$$
Take the limit as $n \to \infty$ and you get for every $\varepsilon>0$
$$
\mathbb{P}(|T-Y|>\varepsilon) =0.
$$

Comment: Let me know if it is clear to you now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you can have $T\ne Y$ only with probability zero.

Convergence in probability is implied by a.s. convergence

Comment: You mean T $\neq$ Y?

Comment: @smbch Yes, of course. Edited the typo